# How to merge three lines at a time

Tags: bash, cat

I have a .txt file with 9 lines:

```
1 2 3 4  
1 2 3 5  
1 2 3 6  
1 2 3 4  
1 2 3 5  
1 2 3 6  
1 2 3 4  
1 2 3 5  
1 2 3 6
```

I want to put the first 3 lines into one line, and the next three lines, and again the last three lines:

```
1 2 3 4 1 2 3 5 1 2 3 6  
1 2 3 4 1 2 3 5 1 2 3 6  
1 2 3 4 1 2 3 5 1 2 3 6
```

however it only gives me one consecutive line

I tried

```
cat old.txt | tr -d '\n' > new.txt
```

Comment: Might work with GNU sed: `sed 'N;N;s/\n/ /g' file`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `paste` to merge together lines.

```
paste -d " " - - - < input.txt
```

The `-d " "` uses a space to delimit between the lines being joined.  Each `-` reads from stdin (and we're redirecting your input file to stdin).  If you wanted to join more lines, just increase the number of `-` etc.